# A function generating random numbers run twice in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For some reason a standard function is ran twice in the template.

For example, if I have this in mount:

```
def mount(_params, _session, socket) do

  random_number = :rand.uniform()

  socket = 
    assign(socket,
      random_number: random_number
    )
  
  {:ok, socket}

end
```

and this is the html template:

```
<%= @random_number %>
```

Then for a fraction of a second I get one number in the browser and then it is repainted with another.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I made a video of this issue. Here is the link [of the video](https://i.imgur.com/8S2nTXj.mp4)

As you can see, when I press the browser's refresh button for a tiny bit you can see the 1st random number which is replaced with the 2nd random number that will stay there.

Comment: Add a logging from `mount/3` and see it gets executed twice.

Comment: yes, in the console if I put `IO.puts("hello")` in the mount function I got it twice in the terminal window as well. Any idea how to prevent that from happening? Is this the default behavior? Isn't it slowing down the website a lot. How do you prevent that from happening? I would like to show/render the random function only once without the flickering between the first and second value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alexei mentioned [`mount/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#c:mount/3) gets called twice, however you have the control of what you want to render.

The easiest way to achieve this is to check if socket is [connected](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#connected?/1):

```elixir
def mount(_params, _session, socket) do

  socket = 
   if connected?(socket) do
    random_number = :rand.uniform()
    assign(socket,
      random_number: random_number
    )
   else
     assign(socket,
      random_number: 0
    )
   end
  
  {:ok, socket}

end
```

Usually the information is deterministic, so for a better user experience is better to render the same thing after the socket is connected.

Comment: Thank you, but it only works because there is the leading zero. If I change the random generation to `Enum.random(1..10)` it will have the same problem even with this `if connected?` condition of yours. I made a video of it, check it here: https://i.imgur.com/0ChE9Jb.mp4 Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no problem, that’s intended behaviour. Assign an empty string if you want nothing to be displayed during the first call.

Comment: Well, OK, I thought it could be done more elegantly though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it cannot be done the other way because it is not guaranteed that the socket connection will happen on the same node, depending on the balancing method you are using, it is possible that the socket connection will happen on other physical server.

Comment: I mean, especially with this random number, it would be great if the function ran only once before both or at least during the first mount GET html render. And this value was used later in the JS initiated websocket render. Do you think it could be done? Do I need to use session for that? What about some more compute intensive tasks? this random number function is easy on resources but I can imagine more resource heavy tasks and running them twice with each page load is not good. Is there any technique or strategy how to mitigate this issue?

Comment: please read carefully what I have written above, you can do all the computations once the socket connection is established, there is no reason to somehow to try and transfer. You can skip entirely the non connected phase and just display a loading message to user.

Answer (score 2):

As it is explicitly stated in the documentation on [`Phoenix.LiveView.mount/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#c:mount/3) callback:

> For each LiveView in the root of a template, `mount/3` is invoked twice: once to do the initial page load and again to establish the live socket.

This is the expected behaviour one could benefit from. If you don’t have any idea of how to benefit from it, simply ignore the fact it gets loaded twice.

Comment: Thank you. But it looks ugly when the the number shows twice. I have recorded it. As I press the refresh browser button, for a fractoin of a second you can see the 1st value and then the 2nd value stays there. Here is the link to the video: https://i.imgur.com/8S2nTXj.mp4